# Blackberry not loading images

Tags: image, blackberry, httpconnection

I've been working on a blackberry project that loads images from the server on a separate thread.  This works fine on the simulator and fine on our test phones, but we have people testing the app in another country and only a few of them can actually view the images.

We're in the process of making a bug submitting template so we can get more accurate information from them and double check the server log, but I was just wondering if anyone knew what would cause this ahead of time.  Any help is appreciated but eventually those bug reports will track it down.

I've tried using an HttpConnection and a StreamConnection but neither one has fixed the issue.

Comment: please read the link:http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

Answer (score 0):

Check what type of internet access they have on their device. If it's BIS-B, you will have to get explicit permission from RIM to be able to use it in your app. Also, if you aren't using it already, I would suggest taking a look at the ConnectionFactory class when creating your connection.

Comment: Right now we're pretty sure it's the server.  We have an Indian tech team running the back end and no access to their code, which is murder.  The theory at the  moment is that they have some kind of time-out we're not aware of and it's returning bad data when the user is on a weak connection.  Is there a way to weaken the crap out of my connection on the simulator?  We're talking like a few bytes per second here.  I'm aware of the connection settings but I can't seem to set the strength low enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have your user's check over wifi only if they can view the images, if they can't it's a problem with the BIS-B probably, if not it's probably their carriers fault (check for DNS errors).